# Why data sizes/lengths are different for the same image between with UIImageJPEGRepresentation and get image by localpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(TZImagePickerController *)picker           
       didFinishPickingPhotoModes:(NSArray<RHPhotoModel *> *)photos  
                     sourceAssets:(NSArray *)assets           
            isSelectOriginalPhoto:(BOOL)isSelectOriginalPhoto      
                        infoArray:(NSArray *)infoArray {

            for (RHPhotoModel *model in photos) {
               UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:model.photoPath];
               NSData *data1  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmpImage,1);

               NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:model.photoPath];

               UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data2];
               NSData *data3  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);

               NSLog(@"data1=%lu, data2=%lu, data3=%lu", (unsigned long)data1.length, (unsigned long)data2.length, (unsigned long)data3.length);
        }

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Use above methods complete back PhotoModel which contains image photoPath;
why I use [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:model.photoPath];
 the data2 is 2497519 byte; 
 however, I use UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:model.photoPath]; NSData *data1  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmpImage,1); 
the data1 is 7234468 byte;

NSLog data:data1 = 7234468 (bytes), data2 = 2497519 (bytes), data3 = 7234468(bytes)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTTHU.png)

Comment: That's not the case for JPEG (the system is different), but it's an analogy: Let's say that you have an image of 20*20. If you transform with quality of 1, it saves each pixels in 8 bytes. Now, if you transform with quality of 0.5, it saves each pixel in 4 bytes, it doesn't matter what was the quality beforehand, each pixels will be saved in an amount of bytes. So it's normal that data1 and data3 have the same amount of bytes. Now, I don't know what was the quality used to save the original image.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think he is asking why data sizes/lengths are different for the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `JPEG` format is for - to "compress data". The information about `.jpg` format can be found on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). The mathematics behind this, however, can be kind of complicated.

The basic idea is that we want the same image data to be saved with a smaller size, so we use different compressing algorithms to convert the image into a smaller one. Compressing data can be `lossy` or `lossless`. For example, `PNG` is lossless, which means the quality will remain the same, while `JPEG` is more commonly used as lossy compression.

Just think of compression as `ZIP` files on a computer, it makes the file size smaller. In Xcode, the size of `JPEG` files can be larger than the original file when the compression quality is set to 1. However, using lower compression quality can result in the compressed file to become more blurry or have weird colors.

Through my experience, I realized that setting the compression quality to 0.4~0.5 preserves better quality with moderate file size. Hope this helps:)