# How to set width and height in an image converted from a base64 string?

Tags: ios, swift, base64, uiimage

I have a question about UIImage convert to base64 String.
I resize my image width and height (1024 x 768) and
then convert this image to a base64 string.
But when I convert this base64 string back to UIImage and look at the image width and height, it is not resized as before(2304.0 x 3072.0).
How to make my base64 String image size correctly?

```
guard let image = image else { return }
print("image => \(image)") 
//image => <UIImage:0x283cce7f0 anonymous {768, 1024}>

guard let base64ImageString = image.toBase64(format: .jpeg(0.2)) else { return }
            
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64ImageString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
let height = decodedimage?.size.height
let width = decodedimage?.size.width
print("====) \(String(describing: width)) / \(String(describing: height))")
//====) Optional(2304.0) / Optional(3072.0)
```

```
public enum ImageFormat {
    case png
    case jpeg(CGFloat)
}

extension UIImage {

    public func toBase64(format: ImageFormat) -> String? {
        var imageData: Data?
        
        switch format {
        case .png:
            imageData = self.pngData()
        case .jpeg(let compression):
            imageData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: compression)
        }
        
        return imageData?.base64EncodedString()
    }

}
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43496557/4233678

Comment: @AriePinto but I want to fix width and height diffirent, not file size.

Comment: @AriePinto Thanks your advice, I try and the same problem.

Comment: Strange, it seems that it's using a x3 multiplicator, something like being a Retina @3. I think that's where you should look. Try with a simulator a device where the UIScreen scale is 2 and see if it's 2 factor too.

Comment: @Larme Yes, I use iphone XS to run this code. How can I fix `x3` problem?

Comment: Ok I think I managed to get the result you wanted, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, the below code resizes your image, and should be added before you change it to base64.

```
guard let image = image else { return }
print("image => \(image)") 
//image => <UIImage:0x283cce7f0 anonymous {768, 1024}>

let desiredSize = CGSize(width: 768, height: 1024)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(desiredSize, false, 1.0)
image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 
desiredSize.width, height: desiredSize.height)))

let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

guard let base64ImageString = resizedImage.toBase64(format: .jpeg(0.2)) else { return }
```